# Proving $\frac{1}{\sqrt x} $is discontinuous at 0

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

The function at hand is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt x} $

I know that is order to prove discontinuity, I have to show the following:

$\forall \delta \gt 0, \exists \varepsilon \gt 0 ~~\text{and} ~~ \exists x ~~ \text{such} ~\text{that} ~~|x - 0| \lt \delta ~~ \text{implies} ~~ |f(x) - f(0)| \geq \varepsilon$

but the function is not defined at $x = 0$, so I can't develop $f(0)$.

I also tried finding a sequence that converges to $0$ but it's image does not converge to the image of $0$, but I'm faced with the same problem there as well.

grateful for any help.

Comment: Your objection is very much correct. It does not make sense to say that $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is continuous or discontinuous at 0, because without any further comments, it is not even defined there.

Comment: For $f$ to be continuous at $x_0$ it is needed that $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$, but in your case $f$ is not defined on that point, so...

Comment: Note: your negation of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity is wrong. Continuity is $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \dots$ hence the negation is $\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall \delta > 0: \dots$, rather than $\forall \delta > 0: \exists \epsilon > 0$.

Comment: thanks for the correction and the confirmations

Comment: This is secretly a question about linguistic convention (i.e. "What does the asked question actually mean?"), marred by the fact that your textbook may not have actually set a convention.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question lying under the question (because like the comments said, the question makes no sense since $f$ is not even defined at $x=0$) is:

*Is it possible to expand by continuity $f(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt x}$ at $x=0$.*

And the answer is no because $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$$

so $f$ does not have a finite limit at $x=0^+$.